# CakePHP shop database design with flexible attributes

Tags: mysql

I'm designing MySQL DB where I have: categories, products, attributes.
Which is the most flexible way to create DB like this.
Products will have different attributes, attributes also can change total price.
SO I'm looking for a some model of DB that can help to design DB that can do all this, but I'm do it in CakePHP

Comment: If your question is only about schema design - remove unrelated tags (cakephp, and "shop" - what a meaningless tag). You probably want to start by looking at [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: Well I'll read about it. Thank's you.